# How do I combine the geoJson of several countries to create a region

Tags: mapping, gis, leaflet, geojson, mapbox

I have the geoJson for every country in the world, but I need to combine several countries to create a region to display on a map.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can probably use bounding boxes to filter out the ones that overlap with the region you're interested in?

Answer (score 0):

Use [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/), load the country files, and create a union of the countries. Output a new GeoJSON file and use that in your map.

Comment: You dont have a tutorial or something you could point me to, do you?